# System Volume Information folder occupied 100 gb

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, disk-cleanup

I have been noticing recently, my C drive gets occupied fully even if there are no bigger programs installed.

Out of 150gb, after uninstalling few programs, the space left was 30gb. Day by day it started decreasing and i saw 20gb today.

I used the disk cleanup tool and it shows only 100mb after selecting all fields.

I was worried still that space was not freeing and check what was wrong..

System Volume information folder occupies 75% of space - meaning 100gb.

Can somebody tell me why 100 gb? I read that this service is important but why is it taking this much of space..please help to remove these unwanted older files if any.

Comment: These files are [important](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314470).  If you delete them your system will not boot.

Comment: I know they are important...but why 100gb..? that's what my question is

Comment: System Volume Information stores your Restore Data and Shadow copies. You can reduce space taken by them

Comment: Because the files that were generated are that large.  You can't reduce the size unless you disable features like System Restore points which I can't suggest.

Comment: @Ramhound oh..so it means taking up 100gb is usual?

Answer (score 1):

*System Volume Information* stores your System Restore Data. If you want to reduce the size Just go to `Control Panel > System > System Protection .` Select the drive for which you want to reduce size. Select configure and Adjust the Max Usage.

This will reduce the number of files and restore states you can have. More space means longer term backup and less means less restore points and less term backup.

Answer (score 1):

I have deleted this folder by using Linux live CD, it come back again but it was small size and no nothing happens my system and it boot correctly. Also you can add premissoin by right-click on system volume information and then click security tab then click add button and then type your username and check full control ckeck-box  and ok all window. now you can go inside system volume information and delete all files if any problem faced do same method for all sub-folders. enjoy