# System volume information folder

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive

What is "system volume information" folder created automatically by windows on each pendrive for?
How can you prevent it from being created?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System Volume Information folder occupied 100 gb](https://superuser.com/questions/777679/system-volume-information-folder-occupied-100-gb)

Answer (score 1):

I run Win 10 build 18363, and for me [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search]
"DisableRemovableDriveIndexing"=dword:00000001
or the Group Policy version of that does not work.
I tried disabling Storage Service, but found doing this interfered with Android devices properly connecting.

Even using Explorer with the show hidden files enabled does not consistently show the  "System Volume Information" directory.

The only solution I have come up with is as follows.
Before ejecting the device
Run as Administrator a command prompt
dir : /ah
Find "System Volume Information"
then
rmdir /s /q ":\System Volume Information"

I hate the ways Microsoft keeps inventing new ways to make my life harder. But this works consistently even though it is a PIA.

Answer (score 0):

The folder has many purposes in general. But on *removable* media, recent Windows 10 versions create it specifically to hold the search index. (The index allows you to quickly search for a file by its name or even contents.)

You can disable removable-media indexing through Registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search]
"DisableRemovableDriveIndexing"=dword:00000001
```

…or through Group Policy (gpedit.msc):

```
Computer Configuration \ Administrative Templates \ Windows Components \ Search

- Do not allow locations on removable drives to be added to libraries
```

Comment: That appears to disable removable media indexing, but does not prevent the creation of the "System Volume Information" folder.  The *only* way I've found to prevent this is to stop the Storage Service.